# Probability using markov inequality

Tags: probability-theory

A positive integer X is selected at random from the set of natural numbers $1,2....50$.
What is $P(X+(96/X))$
I first assumed that selecting any number has probability 1/50 
And used Markov inequality but couldn't get the answer

Comment: Isn't $P\left(X+\frac{96}{X}\right)$ just the image probability of the random variable $Y=X+\frac{96}{X}$? What does it have to do wih Markov's inequality?

Comment: You just  want the probability distribution for values of the random variable $Y=X+\frac {96}X$, yes?  It's a bit tricky because there are duplicate values corresponding to the divisors of $96$.

Comment: How should i proceed

Answer (score 1):

Brute force method:

Start by listing all values of $X$ and the corresponding values of $X+\frac {96}X$:

```
X   X+96/X
1   97
2   50
3   35
4   28
5   24.2
6   22
7   20.71428571
8   20
9   19.66666667
10  19.6
11  19.72727273
12  20
13  20.38461538
14  20.85714286
15  21.4
16  22
17  22.64705882
18  23.33333333
19  24.05263158
20  24.8
21  25.57142857
22  26.36363636
23  27.17391304
24  28
25  28.84
26  29.69230769
27  30.55555556
28  31.42857143
29  32.31034483
30  33.2
31  34.09677419
32  35
33  35.90909091
34  36.82352941
35  37.74285714
36  38.66666667
37  39.59459459
38  40.52631579
39  41.46153846
40  42.4
41  43.34146341
42  44.28571429
43  45.23255814
44  46.18181818
45  47.13333333
46  48.08695652
47  49.04255319
48  50
49  50.95918367
50  51.92
```

Then sort your list to see what values occur more than once:

```
X+96/X  frequency
19.60000    1
19.66667    1
19.72727    1
20.00000    2
20.38462    1
20.71429    1
20.85714    1
21.40000    1
22.00000    2
22.64706    1
23.33333    1
24.05263    1
24.20000    1
24.80000    1
25.57143    1
26.36364    1
27.17391    1
28.00000    2
28.84000    1
29.69231    1
30.55556    1
31.42857    1
32.31034    1
33.20000    1
34.09677    1
35.00000    2
35.90909    1
36.82353    1
37.74286    1
38.66667    1
39.59459    1
40.52632    1
41.46154    1
42.40000    1
43.34146    1
44.28571    1
45.23256    1
46.18182    1
47.13333    1
48.08696    1
49.04255    1
50.00000    2
50.95918    1
51.92000    1
97.00000    1
```

Change frequencies to probabilities by dividing by 50.

@lulu said that the repeated values would be the integer divisors of 96: That would be a more elegant way to proceed ... and I have now convinced myself that this is true.

The equation $x+96/x=k$ has at most two roots for any value $k$.

Let $x=a$ where $ab=96$ and $a$, $b$ are integers.

Then $a=96/b$,so $a+96/a=96/b+b$, meaning that the integer divisors can be used to give integer pairs of roots.

Do the roots only come in integer pairs? Yes, because $X$ must be an integer.